# Calculation into a Field Using Conditional Logic in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to calculate Field Using Conditional Logic in oracle form
like if i select one item then formula one calculate value else formula2

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ordinary IF:

```
if :block.item = 'A' then
   :block.calculated_field := 100 * :block.item_B / 3.14;
elsif :block.item = 'B' then
   :block.calculated_field := 200 * :block.item_c * 1.66;
end if;
```

If that's not it, could you explain it somewhat better? Perhaps even attach screenshot which shows what you need?

Answer (score 0):

use case when like :

```
case when :block.item = 'A' then
   :block.calculated_field := 100 * :block.item_B / 3.14;
when :block.item = 'B' then
   :block.calculated_field := 200 * :block.item_c * 1.66;
end
```